# mongoose exec call with async.parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, mongoose

I have a code like this in my express controller

```
   function (req, res) {
      var queries = [];

      data.forEach(function (item) {
        var query = myModel.findOneAndUpdate({remoteId: item.id}, item, {upsert: true}).exec;

        queries.push(query);
      });

      async.parallel(queries, function (err, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
      });
    });
```

If data array has 3 item, then i have an array of 3 null values.

`async.parallel` function accepts a function with a callback argument, that should be called to properly complete its execution. So `mongoose.Query.exec does` the same. But i recieve an array of null objects as a result.

If i wrap my `exec` call like so

```
var query = function (cb) {
  tournamentsModel.findOneAndUpdate({remoteId: item.id}, item, {upsert: true}).exec(function (err, model) {
    cb(err, model);
  });
};
queries.push(query);
```

everything is ok and i recieve 3 docs from mongo as a result.
Why should i explicitly call a callback passed to a `async.parallel` function call, when `exec` method does the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you directly pass the `exec` function of your query to `async.parallel` as a function to execute, you're losing the `this` context of that function call that contains your query to run.

To use this approach, you would need to call [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to return a new function that will call `exec` with the right `this` context; so something like this:

```
var query = Query.prototype.exec.bind(
    myModel.findOneAndUpdate({remoteId: item.id}, item, {upsert: true})
);
queries.push(query);
```

It's probably cleaner to call `exec` yourself, but pass in the `async` callback to it:

```
var query = function(cb) {
    myModel.findOneAndUpdate({remoteId: item.id}, item, {upsert: true}).exec(cb);
}
queries.push(query);
```